# calculate end to end delay

Tags: python, tcl, ns2, end-to-end

In Computer Network lesson I need to calculate end-to-end delay in python,
I know that I have to use tr output which is created by tcl,
and this tcl is running with ns2.
I know the end-to-end formula but I don't know how to gather data from tr output!
The formula is:
[image]
First 50 lines of tr output:

```
+ 0 0 1 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
- 0 0 1 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
r 0.100213 0 1 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
+ 0.100213 1 4 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
- 0.100213 1 4 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
r 0.200427 1 4 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
+ 0.200427 4 5 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
- 0.200427 4 5 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
r 0.25064 4 5 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
+ 0.25064 5 8 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
- 0.25064 5 8 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
r 0.300853 5 8 tcp 40 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 0 0
+ 0.300853 8 5 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
- 0.300853 8 5 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
r 0.351067 8 5 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
+ 0.351067 5 4 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
- 0.351067 5 4 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
r 0.40128 5 4 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
+ 0.40128 4 1 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
- 0.40128 4 1 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
r 0.501493 4 1 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
+ 0.501493 1 0 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
- 0.501493 1 0 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
r 0.601707 1 0 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 0 1
+ 0.601707 0 1 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
- 0.601707 0 1 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
+ 0.601707 0 1 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
- 0.612587 0 1 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
r 0.712587 0 1 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
+ 0.712587 1 4 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
- 0.712587 1 4 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
r 0.723467 0 1 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
+ 0.723467 1 4 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
- 0.723467 1 4 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
r 0.823467 1 4 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
+ 0.823467 4 5 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
- 0.823467 4 5 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
r 0.834347 1 4 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
+ 0.834347 4 5 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
- 0.834347 4 5 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
r 0.884347 4 5 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
+ 0.884347 5 8 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
- 0.884347 5 8 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
r 0.895227 4 5 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
+ 0.895227 5 8 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
- 0.895227 5 8 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
r 0.945227 5 8 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 1 2
+ 0.945227 8 5 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 1 4
- 0.945227 8 5 ack 40 ------- 2 8.0 0.0 1 4
r 0.956107 5 8 tcp 2040 ------- 2 0.0 8.0 2 3
```

---

Please some body leave a clew how to use tr output data to calculate end-to-end delay in python.

Comment: Show the example of "tr output which is created by tcl"

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with networks, can you distinguish which output parts represent sending a packet, and which receiving?

Comment: That output is not created by some TCL function (AFAIK) - please provide the used code in your question.

Comment: Zac67: The output (out.tr) is created by the "Network simulator ns2".

Comment: @ryhn: There once was some python code for analyzing ns2 trace.tr (year 2006), but I have never seen it actually work. ...... Plenty of awk code for "E2E Delay": Top 25 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bhu2Hunb3JQE_izk0Mtaa8ER3lfQNcDT/view?usp=sharing ....... and all scripts https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uuVmyH8QPe4SRz2g1dnpfCIMvP26pCDj/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What do the columns in the report mean?

Comment: What you're looking for are packet IDs, event statuses, and timestamps. I think I can guess what column is the timestamp (second column; it's monotonically increasing and non-integer) but the others are a bit beyond what I can guess at (it's something to do with the third through fifth columns?).

Answer (score 0):

According to this link:

[the tr output format](http://nile.wpi.edu/NS/analysis.html)

for calculating the end-to-end average delay we need to try these steps:

#### one:

calculate number of packets successfully delivered(N):
N = get maximum sequence number (which is the 11th col)

#### two:

make send time array and implement with -1.
then check if tr output line have `'r'` (for receive) and `'tcp'` (for packet type) and

```
send[seq num] == -1
```

then the time in tr output(which is the second col) is send time.

#### three:

make receive time array.
then check if tr output line have `'r'` (for receive) and `'tcp'` (for packet type)
then the last line of each seq num which pass those properties is the received time (which is the second col in tr output).

#### four:

for each seq num calculate the difference between send and receive and add all seq num and divide it to number of packets(in first step), and you have average end-to-end delay8)).